# Mailchimp subscriber single opt-in form for Shopify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, mailchimp, liquid

We're trying to implement a single opt-in email subscribe form for our MailChimp list on our Shopify site. We're using a custom designed theme that does not have an input field on the theme customization page for a MailChimp action URL.

With this article https://help.shopify.com/manual/using-themes/change-the-layout/theme-newsletter (originally found from https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/mailchimp-newsletter-sign-up-form-with-single-opt-in-199767) using the instructions for "non-sectioned themes" (theme was developed in 2015) -- we end up with this code:

```
{% form 'customer' %}
  {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
    {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
      <p>Thanks for subscribing</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="contact[tags]" value="newsletter">
      <input type="email"
       name="contact[email]"
       id="Email"
       value="{% if customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="commit">Subscribe</button>
    {% endif %}
  {% endform %}
```

Including this code into our theme does nothing, and renders no visible elements on the screen. Inspecting the code we can see a form with two hidden elements on the page.

All we want to do is pass the email address entered in the subscribe form to the Shopify customer database to then import into our MailChimp list via the MailChimp for Shopify plugin.

Been scouring the internet and cannot find any docs for Shopify implementation -- plenty of PHP examples for bypassing the double opt-in feature with jQuery and AJAX but none for Shopify.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the mailchimp app for shopify . https://apps.shopify.com/mailchimp

You can host the php files on a third party host and ajaxify the mailchimp form to make it single step.

Comment: We currently have this plugin installed -- do you have a link to the tut? Is there any problem with cross-domain linking like that?